# Can C# variables be passed to a PHP script?

Tags: c#, php

I want to add a STRING inputted by the user in the C# program to a .PHP script, so that the .PHP script can use this user input. Is this possible?

While searching for this I keep finding POST threads. I do not want to POST to a database, I want to pass a C# STRING(username) to a PHP script(Logincheck.php).

My PHP script is handling the variable $inputusername exactly how I want it to but I can't seem to pass the C# STRING(username) to the $inputusername.

Comment: The Threads about POSTing were right. You don't have to post it to a database, you can just handle it as a string as you intended to.

Comment: Perhaps I need to read more about POST. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify this question - in particular how C# and PHP code related (C# starts some PHP script via locally, C# runs on a client and PHP on separate server, ..) . If your problem is sending data to server running PHP consder deleting as most likely you'll fine tons of posts on this topic and this post likely get downvoted due to "not useful"/"does not show any research" ( https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+post+php gives plenty of examples)

Comment: I'm trying to include client data in a php script.

On the client, I've got an inputfield for the user to input their USERNAME. I want to include this input data in the php file. Reason being this php file is going to pull the username from the database and compare them.



Maybe my workaround idea will give you a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish...

I was thinking about saving the userinput in a txt file(from the client side), then pulling the userinput from the txt file(from the server side)

Comment: I understand php files can return data from the server, but I don't understand how to include data(from the client) with them for computing before return.